# ¿Por qué se necesita cerrar los pipes que no se utilizan?

Tags: c, linux

estoy aprendiendo pipes en c de linux y no entiendo por qué hay que cerrar el lado (escritura o lectura) de un pipe el cual no se está utilizando. Me sucede que no se cuál hay que cerrar y esto provoca que se me cuelgue el programa y no entienda el motivo.
Para quien lo lo conozca una tubería (pipe, cauce o ‘|’) consiste en una cadena de procesos conectados de forma tal que la salida de cada elemento de la cadena es la entrada del próximo. Permiten la comunicación y sincronización entre procesos.

Comment: por favor date el tiempo de leer [ask], tu pregunta no es clara por que no pones el código que usas y donde estas notando el comportamiento que dices; eso y además que agregues que son los pipes de  c, no todo el mundo lo conoce

Comment: No es de nada en concreto, es una pregunta teorica general respecto a un tema el cuál no tiene porqué ser conocido...

Comment: Si no conoces del tema, no se moleste en comentar.

Comment: He leído lo de "Cómo preguntar" y en ningún punto menciona que haya que incluir sección de código obligatoriamente.

Comment: no, pero si se pide que las preguntas sean comprensibles en su contexto; es decir aunque sea teórica debe quedar comprensible incluso si se basa sobre conceptos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En linux los pipes son unidireccionales, hay un extremo donde escribir y un extremo donde leer.

Cada pipe [crea 2 descriptores de archivo](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe): uno para el extremo donde leer otro para el extremo donde escribir.

> `pipe()` creates a pipe, a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication. The array pipefd is used to return two file descriptors referring to the ends of the pipe. `pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe. `pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe. Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe.

Si no los cerras el proceso se puede llegar a quedar sin descriptores, que por lo general en linux el [limite "soft" es de 1024](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt), y el límite "hard" está dado por el máximo de descriptores provistos por el núcleo para cada proceso (1024*1024/2) menos lo que ya está usando el sistema.

> **pipe-user-pages-soft**:
>   Maximum total number of pages a non-privileged user may allocate for pipes
>   before the pipe size gets limited to a single page. Once this limit is reached,
>   new pipes will be limited to a single page in size for this user in order to
>   limit total memory usage, and trying to increase them using fcntl() will be
>   denied until usage goes below the limit again. The default value allows to
>   allocate up to 1024 pipes at their default size. When set to 0, no limit is
>   applied.

Al "cerrar un pipe" que no utilizas se cierra la referencia del descriptor sea de lectura o escritura.

- Si todos los descriptores de archivo que hacen referencia al extremo de escritura se cierran y un proceso intenta leer del descriptor del lado de lectura se recibirá un `EOF`  ([`read(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) retorna 0).
- Si todos los descriptores de archivo que hacen referencia al extremo de lectura se cierran y un proceso intenta escribir en el descriptor del lado de escritura se [generará una signal `SIGPIPE` y si se continúa escribiendo el `write` falla con un error `EPIPE`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to [`read(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) from the pipe will see `end-of-file` ([`read(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) will return 0). If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a [`write(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) will cause a `SIGPIPE` signal to be generated for the calling process. If the calling process is ignoring this signal, then [`write(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) fails with the error `EPIPE`. An application that uses [`pipe(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) and [`fork(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) should use suitable [`close(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close) calls to close unnecessary duplicate file descriptors; **this ensures that `end-of-file` and `SIGPIPE/EPIPE` are delivered when appropriate.**

Esto es útil para detectar si el "proceso lector" o "proceso escritor" están vivos, y cuando se terminó de enviar el flujo de datos.

Usando el ejemplo de [`man pipe 2`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe):

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Proceso padre abre un pipe y recibe dos descriptores: piperead y pipewrite

Se llama a `fork` y se crea un proceso hijo que hereda ambos descriptores (en total 4 del mismo pipe).

Proceso padre cierra su descriptor de lectura así queda un sólo descriptor de lectura (el del hijo). (en total 3 del mismo pipe)

Esto permite saber si el hijo sigue vivo pues si muere ya no hay mas descriptores de lectura en el pipe (el padre recibe `SIGPIPE` o `EPIPE`).

Si el padre no hubiese cerrado su descriptor de lectura, no recibe error o señal y seguiría escribiendo esperando que alguien lo lea (en este caso él mismo) y queda bloqueado.

Al cerrar un descriptor de escritura, y éste es la última referencia al mismo, del otro lado (en el descriptor de lectura) al intentar leer se recibe un `EOF` ([`read(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) retorna 0).

Es por esto que es conveniente que el proceso hijo (o lector) cierre su descriptor de escritura, así puede "escuchar" un `EOF` cuando el proceso padre (o escritor) cierra su descriptor de archivo (de escritura), quedando un sólo descriptor de escritura (el del padre). (en total 2 del mismo pipe)

**Resumiendo:**

Por lo general `pipe` y `fork` se usan para que dos procesos compartan un flujo de datos unidireccional a través de un "archivo virtual" denominado tubo (pipe), este "archivo" tiene dos descriptores, uno por cada extremo del tubo. Al hacer el `fork` el hijo recibe una copia de ambos descriptores.

> Cada proceso cierra el descriptor de archivo (extremo del tubo) que no utiliza para poder saber en que "estado" está el otro proceso y poder detectar el fin del flujo de datos.

En el caso de que la dirección de flujo sea `padre -> hijo` hay un loop en el hijo que lee lo que el padre le envía hasta que encuentra `EOF` ( `SIGPIPE`, `EPIPE` u otras causas), por lo tanto el padre escribe todo el asunto que tiene que entubar y al terminar cierra el descriptor de escritura, esto se lee en el descriptor de lectura como `EOF`, así el hijo sabe que ya terminó el flujo de datos entubados y hace sus cosas (sale del loop).

**bonus**

Para monitorear los descriptores de archivo de un proceso podes usar

```
$ watch -n 1 ls -la /proc/$pid/fd/
```

donde `$pid` es el ID de proceso, para averiguarlo podes `grep`ear la salida de `ps`, onda: `$ sudo ps aux | grep mysql`